# Data Synthesis based on Deep Learning

Tags: neural-networks, dataset, gan, synthetic-data

Is there any open source tool available to synthetically generate a new dataset with the same statistics than the original one?

The objective is to create a new tabular dataset that is private but with the same distribution of the parent one.

Unfortunately, I could only find Generative Adversarial Networks for images.

Comment: SMOTE is used for up/downsampling, but it also generates completely new data based on your original data.

Comment: That is actually a good idea. Never thought about it. I'll think more if it solves my problem. Nevertheless, I was thinking about some kind of data synthetization that would lead me to a new dataset without ever being able to track the original back.